# Short line linking the content of two Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of Bootstrap rows, and I wonder if there's any way to 'link' the content in the columns with a short line, to indicate that they are related? This is how it currently looks: [image]

And this is how I'd like it to look: [image]

This is a sample of the existing code. I'm sure (I hope) I can do this by making using of `info-div:before { some CSS }` but I'm not entirely sure what.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>LAN IP</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="location.lan_ip" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 info-div">
        <p class="field-info">If the first two octets of the device's LAN IP (as reported by Meraki) matches this value, the device will resolve to this location during Meraki import.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `:before`. It *must* have `content:` set or it will not work (css is pseudo-bootstrap).

Since bootstrap padding between columns is always the same, you can just place some element with fixed width and desired position:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.row .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.row .info-div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <label>LAN IP</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="location.lan_ip" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="wrapper info-div">
      <p class="field-info">If the first two octets of the device's LAN IP (as reported by Meraki) matches this value, the device will resolve to this location during Meraki import.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```